# How to access div in Firefox Add-on SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to access the `div` that was right-clicked and log its code (from opening to closing tag) with Add-on SDK.

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
 label: "Log This Div",
 context: contextMenu.SelectorContext("div"),
 contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (e) {' + // e is empty
                '  if (!e) {e = window.event;}' + // window doesnt have event property
                '  console.log(e);' + // result is {}
                '  var text = e.target;' +
                '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                '});',
 onMessage: function (selectionText) {
      console.log(selectionText); // null
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `click` callback is [the actual context `node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu), not an event.

To get the outer markup of the node, you can use [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
 label: "Log This Div",
 context: contextMenu.SelectorContext("div"),
 contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                '  self.postMessage(node.outerHTML);' +
                '});',
 onMessage: function (outerHTML) {
      console.log(outerHTML);
 }
});
```